# API-Platform How to convert request data to Entity

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am fairly new to Symfony and API-Platform,
I have this problem where im trying to add a new entry in my entity

```
{
   class ParentEntity {

      private $id;

      private $companyId;

      private $company;
   }
}
```

And for the security of Parent Entity's collection post, I wanna use the $company entity and process with its voter. somewhat like this

```
App\Entity\ParentEntity:
 collectionOperations:
   post:
     security_post_denormalize: 'is_granted("HAS_ACCESS", request.company)'
```

Is there a way to access/convert the request data into the entity and access the Child Entity from there?

I have looked into @ParamConverter but I cannot understand how I can implement it with API-Platform (since there are no documentation related to this too)

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: API Platform denormalize your entity automatically. There is such security configuration available. See documentation here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/

Comment: Thank you! This is true, and found that my problem is im not formatting my request data properly so symfony denormalizing would work
{
  id: 111
  company: {
    companyId : 123
 }
}